# Adding downloadlink using canvg and amcharts

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvg

I am trying to add a downloadlink to a page that uses AmCharts and CanVG.
The entire graph and img displaying part is all working correctly.

Now i need a downloadlink to provide the user with the image of the graph displayed.

i have already tried to create a HTML link element to the image, but at that moment, i get an error that says "Requested URI to long".

Also i have tried using a form, parsing the source from the image(obtained via jQuery) to a new page, and displaying it there, but also that won't work..

Anybody that can help me? every solution using html/php/jquery/javascript is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have found out, this is not possible due to the length of the url. The best solution will be just to display the image in a div, next to the chart or underneath the chart, as a thumbnail. Trough there the user can just save it into their documents.